# Bootstrap not working in localhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, bootstrap-sass

I am learning Rails with Devise and following this tutorial: https://www.sitepoint.com/devise-authentication-in-depth/

During which I use Bootstrap-Sass for styling. I am having a strange issue where the styles get loaded in production where the application is sitting on Heroku, but in development on my computer I just get the blank, unstyled form. I feel as if I either changed (or did not change) some setting or version of something somewhere, but I am not sure what. I am not sure why something would work fine on Heroku but fall flat on my own computer.

I am using Rails 5. Below is a copy of my Gemfile, is that helps. I will provide additional files/information as needed.

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

#ruby version
ruby "2.3.1"

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.0'
# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg', '~> 0.18'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.0'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 3.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Use Bootstrap for styling
gem 'bootstrap-sass'

# Use Devise for authentication
gem 'devise'

# Fix issues with Bootstrap dropdown menu, Javascript, and Turbolinks
gem 'jquery-turbolinks'

# Perform email sending in background
#gem 'delayed_job_active_record'


group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platform: :mri
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.0.5'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

group :test do
  gem 'rails-controller-testing', '0.1.1'
  gem 'minitest-reporters',       '1.1.9'
  gem 'guard',                    '2.13.0'
  gem 'guard-minitest',           '2.4.4'
end


# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve my own problem with this one (and it goes into my ever-growing pile of dumb mistakes). Instead of renaming my application.css file to .scss as instructed, in my infinite wisdom I made a new .scss file and kept my old .css file. Deleting that let the Bootstrap styles run free. I'm not sure why Heroku didn't have problem with having both those files there, I guess it's just smart enough to understand my dumb mistakes.

I should probably use the new Bootstrap 4 at some point, but for now I like the style I found in the tutorial I was using. Stay tuned for more humorous mistakes.